# TypeScript parameters intersection reduced to never

Tags: typescript

If I have an object like this:

```
type GA = {
    name: 'GameA',
    duration: number
}

type GB = {
    name: 'GameB',
    duration: number
}

type Game = GA | GB;

type Initial<G extends Game = Game> = Pick<G, 'name'>

const Games = {
    GameA: {
        create: (initial: Initial<GA>): GA => {
            throw new Error('not implemented')
        }
    },
    GameB: {
        create: (initial: Initial<GB>): GB => {
            throw new Error('not implemented')
        }
    },
}
```

When trying to invoke the `create` of either by using an object with `name`, `(property) name: "GameA" | "GameB"` like this:

```
const game = Games[objectWithName.name].create(objectWithName)
```

reports an error:

```
Argument of type 'Game' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'Pick<GA, "name" | "duration"> & Pick<GB, "name" | "duration">' was reduced to 'never' because property 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'GA' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
```

**How can I properly type my `Games` object or the `objectWithName`, so that the parameters aren't reduced to 'never'?**

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gglAvFA3gWAFBW1AdgQwFsIAuKAchiIjnIBpMcoATAVwCd9gBLAe1zK5WhAEYR2mAL6ZMoSLABCSVIxwFiZStQX1V2Npx79BwsRIzSMs8NCrFl8KAB9FAbhkY50AJK5uPfAAbAB4YKAgAD2AIXGYAZ1hqB2oAPmUABW4AYwBrULoKdQhyFI8vWAhgOwhggDlwqJj4xOIAbXIi8gBdNOQAUSjOLOBQ6gKUPGoyeslSq08bKABhdgguXnZQhujYhOreqAAKbj9gMl9-biDQlIBKJDSYMsXqlbXgDa3Ineb95QmsqsuKRlkCPpsYGlLNZ5NU4kteIFAhBhnxcP89FBWgBpKAnFoQdqdLpdMivMGfGCVarBbEpObQjBZfhxYAEuJk6jwxHI1H8DFYHDVOBkdCCpjYQHvEHHU5XQL3RBpMUS1VQYAAC3YvAA7ngIHq+uxtexDh1eGzuIQwMjiLhosxyLdMUxLK6GOKCQpRS6cFLgWRZZcguc5dcYAo7mSlEqVJ61eqtbr9YbjRszbgLXjrbaYg6nb7sG6cJIPYzmbhWSxhIQQABVOLiaqh4MhP7IFVqKZQABEwp7HqYBi4aLIAGYpB4K1WJkUyJqILVqAB5ABmABUNRBqlBJMo2IRaw2m9R3EyWWyAWDoHvkHDWgej432NUAHRFLpn6dsgDmSWQ-rRIcj71s+1S3EAA)

Comment: Can you add the type definitions for `Initial<T>`, `GA`, and `GB` directly to your post? Not just in the playground.

Comment: There is no error in playground

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks, I've updated the link

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me, object literals can specify *only* known properties and you're using `Pick` so duration is not a known property on the type `Initial`. Did you miss the earlier error?

Comment: Let's say I have an implementation that populates the duration within create

Comment: Except that the later error is meaningless until you fix the earlier one. Here is the (more meaningful) error now: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gglAvFA3gWAFBW1AdgQwFsIAuKAchiIjnIBpMcoATAVwCd9gBLAe1zK5WhAEYR2mAL6ZMoSLABCSVIxwFiZStQX1V2Npx79BwsRIzSMs8NCrFl8KAB9FAbhkY50AJK5uPfAAbAB4YKAgAD2AIXGYAZ1hqB2oAPmUABW4AYwBrULoKdQhyFI8vWAhgOwhggDlwqJj4xOIAbXIi8gBdNOQAUSjOLOBQ6gKUPGoyeslSq08bKABhdgguXnZQhujYhOreqAAKbj9gMl9-biDQlIBKJDSYMsXqlbXgDa3Ineb95QmsqsuKRlkCPpsYGlLNZ5NU4kteIFAhBhnxcP89FBWgBpKAnFoQdqdLpdMivMGfGCVarBbEpObQjBZfhxYAEuJk6jwxHI1H8DFYHDVOBkdCCpjYQHvEHHU5XQL3RBp

Comment: Looks like you're maybe looking for a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look shortly and if you post an answer how to fix the example above it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gglAvFA3gWAFBW1AdgQwFsIAuKAchiIjnIBpMcoATAVwCd9gBLAe1zK5WhAEYR2mAL6ZMoSLABCSVIxwFiZStQX1V2Npx79BwsRIzSMs8NCrFl8KAB9FAbhkY50AJK5uPfAAbAB4YKAgAD2AIXGYAZ1hqB2oAPmUABW4AYwBrULoKdQhyFI8s-jjgROIE5HQsHDsaMnqmJiz2CC5SKAAKbj8AwLJff24g0LgUgEoyR0Q01rbl4AALdl4AdzwIbYBRdg32XvJcXiruQjBAiGJcaOZyab02yyZJBgbsJoUWl-bOt0yP1BuNhlBRkNQgoZnMlAsVF9ljg1httrhdlADkcTmcLlcbncHk9-jg3mTPpZMOVcJUoABzagIOZJOovIokABETTgnM%20TAMXD4AgAjAAGMVSMoVC6goI8qAjOUhJppNlIjncpl8qVWDA0un03i8ZhNZI1ADajOIcAAdEUALq2jpdaK9a00Z56g1VET4U2s6oQOIWgZjeVM%203UJ0u7og8OBHleoA) minimal repro of the issue makes it clear that an  `Initial<GameA>` can't be assigned to a `GameA`, given the Pick has eliminated some of the required fields.

This is the origin of your problem. This is also demonstrated by `goodGame` where using a valid GameA object as a 'prototype' DOESN'T face an issue in the create call.

```
type GA = {
    name: 'GameA',
    duration: number
}

type GB = {
    name: 'GameB',
    duration: number
}

type Game = GA | GB;

type Initial<G extends Game = Game> = Pick<G, 'name'>

const Games = {
    GameA: {
        create: (initial: Initial<GA>): GA => {
            throw new Error('not implemented')
        }
    },
    GameB: {
        create: (initial: Initial<GB>): GB => {
            throw new Error('not implemented')
        }
    },
}

const gameA : Game = {
    name:"GameA",
    duration:100
}

const initialGameA : Initial<Game> = {
    name:"GameA",
}

const goodGame = Games[gameA.name].create(gameA)

const badGame = Games[initialGameA.name].create(initialGameA)
```